# How to insert PHP value into HTML form?

Tags: php, html, forms

My code is

```
 <form action = "insert.php" method = "POST">
  <div class="title-block">
         <input type="text" name="rater_full_name" />
         </div>
              <div class="title-block">
         <input type="text" name="rater_company_name" required />
         </div>
     <div class="title-block">
         <input type="text" name="rater_ref" />
         </div>
          <div class="title-para">
        <textarea rows="5" name="rater_suggestion"></textarea>
         </div    <div align="left"><div class="btn-block">
          <input type="hidden" name="PID" value="<?php echo $PID; ?>">        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit Feedback</button>
          
        </div> 
      </form>
```

It's not storing the variable $PID value, it is storing complete code inside quotations("")  Please suggest best way to do so..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to save it as a `.php` file and host it on a server that has PHP installed.

Comment: but the form is in HTML, so does it work after saving in php. I mean form look will remain the same or changed?

Comment: Of course it works. PHP is designed to be woven into HTML like this.

Comment: It's working now, thank you @NiettheDarkAbsol

Answer (score -1):

Save the file as .php rather than .html

Comment: Please close duplicate questions instead of answering them.